# Cannot Decode JSON API response

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have built an API for my shipping quote system. I feed it values and I get rate quotes back. It works fine but I cannot decode the JSON response. I get a NULL response and I'm not sure whats up. According to validaters the JSON is correct.

So what I essentially do is encode a PHP array on one side and I want to parse that on the other side using a browser and PHP. However, I get a NULL response.

Here is the JSON. Let me know if you need more.

```
{"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"}
```

I just want to decode this so I can parse it. If there is another way to parse please let me know.

Also, I searched SOF and the similar issues people were having here didn't help me.

This is the code I use to generate the JSON.

```
    <?php
    //include ('mysql_connect.php');

    $result = mysql_query('select * from quote where user_id = "'.$user_id.'" order by netCharge asc limit 1');

    if (!$result) {
        die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
    }

    if (!$result) echo mysql_error();

    $api_data = array();
    $api_count = '0';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $api_data[carrier] = $row['carrier'];
    $api_data[charge] = $row['netCharge'];
    $api_data[service_days] = $row['serviceDays'];

    $api_count++;

    }

    $api_data = json_encode($api_data);

    print_r($api_data);

    ?>
```

This is what I'm using to grab that JSON data:

```
    <?php

    $input = file_get_contents('api_request.php?dest_zip=66101&weight=200&class=50&ltl_shipment=X&Residential_Delivery=X');
    echo $input;

    $obj = json_decode($input);
    var_dump($obj);

    ?>
```

Comment: Where will you decode it? In browser using javascript? or using PHP at server side? More details are required.

Comment: I would use PHP to decode.

Comment: And PHP's `json_decode()` didn't work? Or is it that the JSON is not getting from place to place as you expect it would?

Comment: 'json_decode()' did not work. All I really want to do is parse this response.

Comment: try [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to maybe get a hint what might be the problem.

Comment: Not quite use how to use that. Just stick it right after the current code just as you typed it?

Comment: [Here's](http://3v4l.org/cPolH) a demo. (I purposefully *made* the json input wrong)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_last_error_msg() in api_testing.php on line 8

Comment: That means you php version is too old, try [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-last-error.php) instead.

Comment: `4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. Ops. Please paste all your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: I have added all my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wrote the code I used 'Enter' to give me spaces between lines of code. For some reason that translated to the JSON and that's why it wasn't working. I just deleted all the extra empty lines in my file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

```
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: Absolutely have. No luck.

Comment: The output of json_encode() is not the result you need? Can you add the output you expect to have?

Comment: The out that the code you provided would give. Just a PHP array.

Comment: I think you should post the part of the code where you build the json data.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

The built-in function `json_decode` ([see doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) should help. According to the official document, `NULL is returned if the JSON cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.`

**I doubt the JSON string you read is actually NOT as same as PHP reads.** Please make sure the string is NOT HTML escaped. And it is very **important** that keys and values in a JSON should be quoted by double quote. Single quote is malformed JSON, which might be considered as syntax error.

### Example

To be a good demo, I put json string in file and then decode it using `test.php`.

In `example.json`:

```
{"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"}
```

In `test.php`:

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents('example.json');
echo $input;
// {"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"}

$obj = json_decode($input);
var_dump($obj);
// object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
//   ["carrier"]=>
//   string(12) "R&L Carriers"
//   ["charge"]=>
//   string(5) "99.13"
//   ["service_days"]=>
//   string(23) "Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"
// }
```

Comment: Wish it was that easy for me. I do what you are but with a variable and not the actual JSON. Just get a big 'NULL'.

Comment: What PHP version are you using. Make sure `json_decode` is supported. Second, add a line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `json_decode`. Something went wrong I think.

Comment: How do you get your json result ? are you sure, you're feeding the plain json data to the json_decode, and it does not contains any "extra" characters? (headers, error messages, etc.etc.? )

Comment: Here's what I do and it might be completely wrong. I take a PHP array and encode it. Then echo or print_r that JSON. Then I use a different file to 'file_get_contents' that JSON and put it into a variable. Next is 'json_decode' which results in NULL. If I inspect element on the JSON all I see is that text and the surrounding body(which does nothing).

Comment: How do I make sure its not HTML escaped?

Comment: The way I showed in example should work. No escaping.

Comment: That's how I've been doing it from the beginning.

Comment: Heres the output from what you showed '{"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"} NULL'

Comment: Well the problem was that I had line breaks in my code. Not like code line break but just were I had hit 'Enter' so I could have a clear space in between code. As soon as I removed those everything worked fine. Very odd.

Comment: Now the problem scope is reduced to link breaks. So you can remove all line breaks in your query api.

Answer (score 0):

Your response has an extra `</div>` in it.

Delete the div so that's valid JSON and the decode function will work.

http://trumrates.com/trumrates/rate/quote/signin/api_request.php?dest_zip=66101&weight=200&class=50&ltl_shipment=X&Residential_Delivery=X

Yields:

`{"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"}
</div>`

Comment: That was not happening earlier. I deleted that however.

Comment: So it's still not working? I was able to run: `$test = '{"carrier":"R&L Carriers","charge":"99.13","service_days":"Wednesday Oct. 22, 2014"}';

$obj = json_decode($test);
var_dump($obj);` and get the expected results. I did notice your URL has a couple of redirects going on if the session cookies aren't set.